# SQLite Dynamic where-clause for ToggleButtons

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite, togglebutton

I would like to create something like a dynamic where clause but struggle with it.

**FrameWork:**
I want to use 4 Togglebuttons, which obviously return me with "Togglebutton.ischecked()" a true or false boolean. According to that I want to choose the correct courser of my database. 
The Togglebuttons have the values "Basic","Common","Uncommon" and "Rare".
If a Togglebuttons is pressed it calls the DB Method which than yields to setting up my layout with the data of the Database.

**Issue:** *I have problems creating a correct Query which changes the whereArguments and whereClause accordingly. From my Understanding the whereClause needs a String and the whereSelection needs a StringArray.*

**What I tried:**

1. I tried creating a StringArray accordingly, which yields the problem of having a fixed index. Therefore I had issues with creating a smart logic, which yields the correct StringArray,

*e.g. if ToggleButton (tb) tbBasic = true, tbUncommon = false, tbCommon = true, tbRare = true, I would need something like String[] whereArgs = new String[] {"Basic","Common","Rare"} whereas I can not create that accordingly with a something like a "add" method.*

2. Therefore I tried using an Arraylist which makes adding and deleting according to the toggles very easy.

E.g. if my DBHelper method getAllHeros is called I can create a new Arraylist each time which yields me the correct whereArgs.

```
ArrayList<String> whereArgsList = new ArrayList<>();

        if(btnBasic){
            whereArgsList.add("Basic");
        }
        if(btnCommon){
            whereArgsList.add("Common");
            }
        if(btnUncommon){
            whereArgsList.add("Uncommon");
        }
        if(btnRare){
            whereArgsList.add("Rare");
        }
    Cursor c = db.query("TableHeros", null,whereClause, whereArgsList.toArray(new String[0]),null,null,null,null);
```

**The Issue with that is that obviously the whereClause has to be updated accordingly aswell. So in a Case of the Arraylist being longer than one Element the whereClause would need the same amount of elements aswell.**

I hope I made my point clear and I am open to try any Suggestions

Comment: Your current call to `db.query` does not appear to select any columns, nor is it clear what the underlying query should be.  Can you add your intended raw SQLite query to the question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the SQLiteDatabase's query method's 2nd parameter specifies the columns, null equating to * (all columns). The underlying SQL/query would be `SELECT * FROM TableHeros ........`

Comment: @MikeT Thanks, didn't know that.  But about the `whereClause`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yep what is needed by the WHERE clause needs to be clarified whether the toggles are for a single column or individual columns and also whether AND or OR's should be used or perhaps even an IN or NOT IN.

Comment: @MikeT, I always want all columns, that is why I did not really specify that. Sorry :). So using null is just fine for gaining all columns

Comment: yes null is fine for all columns, although if you have lots of columns with lots of data per column then you might encounter problems or experience slow processing then you might well consider being more exact and use specific columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified what the WHERE clause should look like. However assuming that:

- a) the buttons all apply to a single column (**COL_TASK_TITLE** (which equates to the String title) is used in the code below) and
- b) that should multiple buttons be true that you want to select rows that contain both values and
- c) also assuming that if none are selected that you want all rows then the following might be along the lines of what you want

:-

```
public Cursor getMyRows(boolean btnBasic, boolean btnCommon, boolean btnUncommon, boolean btnRare) {

    ArrayList<String> whereArgsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String whereclause = null;
    String[] whereargs = null;

    if(btnBasic){
        whereArgsList.add("Basic");
    }
    if(btnCommon){
        whereArgsList.add("Common");
    }
    if(btnUncommon){
        whereArgsList.add("Uncommon");
    }
    if(btnRare){
        whereArgsList.add("Rare");
    }
    StringBuilder whereclauseToBe = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s: whereArgsList) {
        if (whereclauseToBe.length() > 1) {
            whereclauseToBe.append(" OR ");
        }
        whereclauseToBe.append(COL_TASK_TITLE); //<<<<<<<<< change to your column
        whereclauseToBe.append(" = ? ");
    }
    if (whereclauseToBe.length() < 1) {
        Log.d("WHERE CLAUSE","No selections so WHERE CLAUSE and WHERE ARGS have been set as null");
    } else {
        whereclause = whereclauseToBe.toString();
        Log.d("WHERE CLAUSE ", "The generated WHERE CLAUSE would be... WHERE " + whereclauseToBe.toString());
    }
    if (whereArgsList.size() > 0) {
        whereargs = new String[whereArgsList.size()];
        whereargs = whereArgsList.toArray(whereargs);
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c =  db.query(TABLE, null,whereclause, whereargs ,null,null,null,null); //<<<<<<<<<< Change TABLE to table name
    return c; //<<<<<<<<<< Could just do `return db.query(TABLE.........`
}
```

- Note this is a method within a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper aka the Database Helper.

The above was tested using (from an activity) :-

```
    db.getMyRows(false,false,false,false);
    db.getMyRows(true,false,false,false);
    db.getMyRows(true,false,true,false);
    db.getMyRows(false,true,true,false);
    db.getMyRows(false,false,false,true);
    db.getMyRows(true,true,true,true);
```

The results written to the log were :-

```
10-22 04:44:23.975 1429-1429/? D/WHERE CLAUSE: No selections so WHERE CLAUSE and WHERE ARGS have been set as null
10-22 04:44:23.975 1429-1429/? D/WHERE CLAUSE: The generated WHERE CLAUSE would be... WHERE title = ? 
10-22 04:44:23.975 1429-1429/? D/WHERE CLAUSE: The generated WHERE CLAUSE would be... WHERE title = ?  OR title = ? 
10-22 04:44:23.975 1429-1429/? D/WHERE CLAUSE: The generated WHERE CLAUSE would be... WHERE title = ?  OR title = ? 
10-22 04:44:23.975 1429-1429/? D/WHERE CLAUSE: The generated WHERE CLAUSE would be... WHERE title = ? 
10-22 04:44:23.975 1429-1429/? D/WHERE CLAUSE: The generated WHERE CLAUSE would be... WHERE title = ?  OR title = ?  OR title = ?  OR title = ?
```

- Note TABLE and COL_TASK_TITLE were from a table and would need to be changed.

Comment: Hey @MikeT, thanks for the answer. After testing I found one more bug. We can not toString() on a null object. Therefore I changed **whereClausetoBe.toString** to **String.valueof(whereClausetoBe)** which is able to handle a null object. But I dont really know how to fix the issue with the Arraylist.. Is there also a smart way of not invoking on a null object instead of using try and catch?

Comment: @Christian.gruener ooops will have a look. Didin't test the Cursor aspect as that would be quite some work.

Comment: @Christian.gruener have edited the answer, this has also been tested albeit it that no rows were ever returned as it was tested on an existing table/column.

Comment: Thank you sir! That totally solved my problem!! :) Would appreciated an upvote of my question ;)